# Can't show past events of my facebook fanpage

Tags: facebook

When I try to show events of my fanpage (id = 212435238796460) using GraphAPI it shows nothing, but when I redirect to fanpage events I see all past events.

My FQL :
SELECT name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description, eid 
            FROM event WHERE  eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 212435238796460)

GraphAPI:
212435238796460?fields=events

Direct link to fanpage events:
http://www.facebook.com/tworczyniezalezni?sk=events

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

SELECT name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description, eid FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 212435238796460 and start_time>0) order by start_time DESC